# Creating a trigger to Insert in to Another table based on SUMMATION value in another table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I am trying to write a Trigger to Update a column(Columns Name:Sponsor Tier) in table(Table Name: Sponsor) when I Insert the data in to another table(Table: Sponsored).

If the SUM of Sponsorship Amount in > 5000 , I want to set the Sponsor tier to 'Platinum'
 If Sponsorship Amount <=5000 and >500 , I want to set Sponsor Tier to "GOld".

How would I do this?

Comment: There  is two updates.

Comment: show some sample data on both tables along with column names  and show expected result as well

Answer (score 0):

Try this one I hope it's should work

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS upd_sponsored;

DELIMITER $$

    CREATE TRIGGER upd_sponsored BEFORE UPDATE ON `Sponsored`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
      IF (OLD.Amount>5000) THEN
            SET NEW.Sponsor_Tier = 'Platinum';
      ELSE IF (OLD.Amount<=5000 AND OLD.Amount>500) THEN
            SET NEW.Sponsor_Tier = 'GOld';
      END IF;
    END$$
```